# projects in solution

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I am wondering how divide large scale application into projects.
Does I need to create:
1. one project for the data access layer.
2. one project for the business logic layer.
3. one project for the web application.
?

should I put the data access layer and the business login layer together?

in addition, does the data access layer should depend on the business login layer?

should the web application depend on the data access layer directly? (does is should use methods from the data access layer on work using objects from the business login layer)?

right now I have two projects:
1. web application.
2. all the code including data access and business objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically keep my projects seperate:

Solution
->Presentation Tier
->Business Tier
->Data Tier

I then add reference from Presentation to Business and Business to Data. I never let my Presentation interact directly from Data. Typically I also utilize services in my Business layer that can be deployed to separate location if necessary.

Comment: @Dustin Laine: How do your Data Tier returns Business objects if the Data Tier doesn't have dependency on the Business Tier?

Comment: Depending on how you write your code of course, you probably want to create another project for the Model for others to share.  I don't follow DDD to the T so I have both MyApplication.Model and MyApplication.Business.

Comment: My data tier will return data, not business objects. For example a datatable, from which the business tier will turn into an business object or list of business objects.

Comment: (Not worth a separate answer - because this one is good) If your business tier is very complex consider splitting it into a couple of packages based on functionality.  And being a UI person, I often have a separate project for re-usable UI components.

Comment: @Liz: Do you meen separate big applications into modules? if so - this is also what I am tring to do.

Comment: @e36M3, yes especially with an MVC architecture.

Comment: +1 - I have had success using exactly this design several times in the past. (Where Data Tier = TSQL, Business Tier = C# DLL, and Presentation Tier = Winforms, ASP, or WCF.)

Comment: @Dustin Laine: If I use the entity framework for example, I can't return datatable. At most I can return the object presentation of the entity framework. is this what you ment?

Comment: Naor, for example if you're using something like Entity Framework the generated objects are your Model.  For example classes like Student and Class.  My business tier usually contains things like SchoolManager that might provide business functionality over all things school related, and moves in and out classes from the Model.  Every layer needs to know about the Model.

Comment: @e36M3: But here I make dependency on how the model implemented.. the data tier should know only interfaces from the model/data tier..

Comment: Again you would have to be familiar I guess with ORMs in order to understand what I'm saying.  The Model is preferably POCO classes.  It's something that can easily be explained in a chat.  I suggest reading up on some common architectural guides.

Comment: @e36M3: I've read many articles about the framework entity and nHibernate and saws before the term POCO, but I can't understand how it helps me repalce the data tier without changes in the business tier.

Answer (score 5):

Download Microsoft Application Architecture Guide, 2nd Edition here, I'm now reading it and it is very helpful on the subject:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ce40e4e1-9838-4c89-a197-a373b2a60df2

Comment: @Joshua Girard: Great find, I will read it because it seens helpful, but it 560 pages - and I have to decide soon..

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by a "very large project."

We are writing an MVC application and we have split it into several assemblies... one for each of the databases we're accessing.  But it's not just DAL, it's got SOME special logic in there as well.  This assembly also has some common functionality.

We then have a common web project.

We then have a web project for each of the 3 sites that use this data, they all depend on the common project.

It will probably be easier to maintain and develop if you split it into at least 3 assemblies.  Here's why.

1. It forces you to have a separation of concerns, need to get something out of the data? Put it in the data assembly.  Need to modify some javascript? Put it in the presentation.
2. It allows for specialization.  You can get a stud back-end developer, or a javascript guru, and they can work on just their assembly without effecting anyone else.
3. If something on the front end changes, and you want to go to a new front end, there's a good chance the DAL and business layer wouldn't need as many changes.